# Псевдонимы sql

Tags: sql

Нужно создать процедуру с рекурсией в sql. Чтобы в рекурсии устанавливались все время одни и те же таблицы под всегда разными псевдонимами. Можно ли в этом случае задать псевдонимы переменными. Или как вообще поступить в данном случае?

Answer (score 1):

Можно.. напиши пример, скажем, что неправильно, просто в ХП, когда будешь создавать запрос для создания таблиц в имя надо дописывать время. Ну или можно создать таблицу с версионностью твоих таблиц делать туда запрос и устанавливать следующею версию для новых таблиц

Comment: напиши короткий пример пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

можно создать sequence если доступно и включать его значение в имя псевдонима. или же хранить счетчик в какой-то таблице